# Scopes in compiler construction

Tags: compiler-construction

I am writing a compiler, and looking for a way to handle scopes.

Would creating a class which contains a stack of map of pair of values and key a good idea?

When I enter in a new scope, I insert a new map at the top of the stack, if the scope is a sub scope, I copy all the element of the map of the previous scope to the new map.

Comment: The way to handle scope will depend on the language you are compiling: for a C like language..you don't need to copy the elements into the new scope (there are no nested function definitions and the callee cant access the caller's local vars). For a Pascal like language you need a way to access the outer scope..this typically will be a pointer to the caller stack frame. Finally, if you are compiling a language which allows you to build closures, the stack idea will not be sufficient at all.

Comment: @user1666959 It is a compiler for the language Tiger which contains nested functions. So if I copy the previous stack for nested functions instead of simply having a pointer to it, the performance will be worse but it will still work, right?

Comment: Ah. Appel's stuff. Don't remember the syntax but consider: fun f1() {fun f2 { fun f3() {}}}. Are you going to copy f1's variables to f2 and then all that to f3? And don't forget about mutually recursive functions: fun MR { fun f1() {...f2...} fun f2() {...f3...} fun f3(..f1...f2) {}}.

Answer (score -1):

I do not recommend using a map at all, since it doesn't work for methods (given that they are polymorphic). What I did in my compiler was to pass a certain [`IContext`](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/structure/IContext.java) to a method that has methods like [`resolveField`](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/classes/CodeClass.java#L713), `resolveMethod` etc. If a scope cannot find a field with the name from `resolveField(String name)`, it calls `resolveField` on it's parent scope, until the root scope (usually the class) returns `null`, in which case the field 'cannot be resolved'.

Internally, I would maintain a List of Fields (and methods, ...) (that you need anyway if your language supports them) instead of a Map. The `resolveField` would then iterate through the List, compare the name parameter with the actual field name and return the field instance if the names match.

Comment: Why do you say that a map doesn't work for a method? Is it because the language you are compiling is polymorphic? As far as I know, tiger is not. Even so, the map could help reduce the search space by mapping a name onto a list of possible definitions. Maps have significant overhead, but if there are a lot of names in a scope the faster lookup could be a win.